# Bash - expected file extension on tab

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not sure if this is something that can be done in the Linux/Unix terminal, so I thought I'd ask.

For certain programs (unfortunately I can't think of any besides `bibtex` off the top of my head, which on tab auto-'extends' the .aux extension) when I'm finished typing out the file name (minus dot and extension) in front of it, I've noticed that if I hit `tab`  it will 'auto-complete' the dot + file extension.

Is this something you can actually control somehow ? For example, if I wrote a bash script (we'll call it `compile.sh`) that only worked with *.tex files, I could do the following:

```
$ ./compile.sh nameOfProgram -- tab and autocomplete .tex extension --
```

Certainly it's not inherent to the bash script itself, but by some other means that recognizes I'm using said executable.

Sometimes, as is often the case while using LaTeX, there are multiple files with the same base name but different extensions in the same directory - I would like it to only accept that which has the predefined extension.

Comment: is [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885851) perhaps what you are looking for?

Comment: @Matthias This too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to define a custom completion function for `compile.sh` which only matches `*.tex` files. Writing a *good* completion function is a broad task, but you can do something very simple with

```
# Add to your .bashrc file to enable in every shell, not just
# the current shell
complete -G '*.tex' compile.sh
```

which will only treat files matching `*.tex` as valid completions for any argument to `compile.sh`.

Comment: I see, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've also found it over in Appendix J in the tldp Advanced Bash Scripting Guide http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html. How cool! And simple!